# Update command in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm currently trying to update an amount.

```
update Stipend
set Amount = Amount * 1.4
where SubjectId IN ('10111','20022','30033') ;
```

The `update` is able to run correctly but the only thing that does not get updated is `SubjectId` '10111', as the amount stays the same.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: in your query you have 10111, but the `SUBJECTID` you want to update is 10011.